# How can I batch convert all of my video files to AAC audio without converting the video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, batch, conversion

I've used XMedia Recode to do this and it works great. I set video to "copy", audio to "convert", and it takes 2 minutes for a 2GB file. There's two problems with it for batch work though. It doesn't detect files in subfolders, and you have to specify the audio bitrate.

I'd like to be able to say convert everything in Z:\Videos, inherit the audio bitrate, and put the file named "(original file)-converted" in the original folder. Is that possible, maybe using ffmpeg? Running Windows 8.1.